# Why does variable.constructor === Object sometimes returns a true and sometimes a false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have the following scenario:

In my test, I declare a variable

```
 const query = {
      where: { publishedCount: { inq: [2, 3] } },
  };
```

and when I check if the variable is an object using .constructor === Object I get true

```
console.log(query.constructor === Object); // true
```

In the next line I pass the same variable to the function and inside that function the comparison returns **false**

```
app.models.Group.find(query);

function find(query) {
  console.log(query) // prints: where: { publishedCount: { inq: [2, 3] } },
  console.log(query.constructor) // prints: function Object() {}
  console.log(query.constructor === Object) // FALSE
}
```

My code runs on Node v8.10.0 and Jest runner v23.4.2. In both cases, printing query returns correct object and printing `query.constructor` returns `function Object() {}`

I made a simple check using JSBIn and there the comparisons return true two times
https://jsbin.com/wotuperode/edit?js,console

What is this happening?

PS. I can't change how I check for Object type because one of the libs from node_modules checks in this way

**UPDATE 1**

The function that I call is the `find` function from `loopback` library. This find function is available in every data model in your app.
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/dao.js#L1897

The comparison used by lib is here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-postgresql/blob/master/lib/postgresql.js#L554
(the lib adds postgres connector to loopback)

My full code

```
 describe("Tests", () => {
   it("update array of elements", async () => {
      // creating objects etc
      ...
      const query = {
          where: { publishedCount: { inq: [2, 3] } },
      };
      await app.models.Group.find(query); // my code has await but even without await the comparison still returns false
      ... 
      // expects etc
   });
 });
```

**UPDATE 2**

It's only happening in my **tests** when I run code using **Jest** runner.

Comment: Did you try logging `query` in your function ?

Comment: Does your code ever create another `query` object? How does it create this object?

Comment: "*one of the libs from node_modules checks in this way*" - can you please be more specific about your actual problem, including the library that you are calling (with a link to code and/or docs) as well as your actual code? We need a [mcve] - the jsbin that doesn't reproduce the problem won't help.

Comment: @Zenoo I updated my question. The query looks the same in both cases.

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope, I execute the find function in the next line, just after creating query object

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code in question...

Comment: @AxelF I updated, take a look now

Comment: @Bergi Check now, I added as much as possible. It runs on Node so I need to prepare repository. I can do it later because right now I don't have time for that